# Google sheets formulas

Tags: google-sheets

I am wanting to Match G with A (A2-A17 and A21-A33 separately) and if row B is checked or 'True' for either section to return the date (A1 and/or A20) to H next to the correct Stop. IF it is false then I don't want it to return anything. I'm having a difficult time figuring out how to string formulas together to get it to work. If I need to explain something better or if anyone has any suggestions please let me know! All help is appreciated!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UWpRf.jpg

Edit:
Here is an example sheet!
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ImpmNgVMJoc79Wf2T9Nm3Kstem9wzITTrce4cTyBz28/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired result

Answer (score 1):

I have added a new sheet ("Erik Help") to your sample spreadsheet. I've left the following formula in H2, highlighted in green:

`=ArrayFormula(IF(B2:B10=TRUE,TEXT(A1,"m/dd"),)&IF((B2:B10)*(B13:B21),", ",)&IF(B13:B21=TRUE,TEXT(A12,"m/dd"),))`

This formula assumes that your sample setup accurately reflects your actual setup, particularly in that your stop names running G2:G10 will always be the same and in the same order as those running in A2:A10 and in A13:A21. If that will not necessarily be the case, the formula can be modified.

It was also written assuming that you actually only have two date-sets. If you will actually have numerous date-sets for each stop, this formula method will not be efficient. (And if this is the case, I would suggest, as always, that your post explanation and sample data reflect your real-world need as accurately as possible in order to avoid wasting time on solutions that won't suit your actual need.)

If you break this formula down, it is just three smaller IF formulas concatenated with the `&` symbol:

`IF(B2:B10=TRUE,TEXT(A1,"m/dd"),)`

This will return the A1 date in the format you have it in wherever B2:B10 is checked (or return nothing if it is not checked).

`IF((B2:B10)*(B13:B21),", ",)`

This will add in a comma-space combination if both the B2:B10 and (*) the B13:B21 checkboxes are checked, since that is the only time you'd need the comma-space (or return nothing if both are not checked).

`IF(B13:B21=TRUE,TEXT(A12,"m/dd"),)`

This will return the A12 date in the format you have it in wherever B13:B21 is checked (or return nothing if it is not checked).

I will add that, even for just two blocks, as you currently have in your sample spreadsheet, I would not set it up this way. If you are interested in alternative setups, let me know.